# Is it possible to change a queryset using AJAX?

Tags: python, ajax, django, django-queryset

I have querysets for comments which looks like this:

```
comment_list = Comment.objects.filter().order_by('-score__upvotes')
new_comments_list = Comment.objects.filter().order_by('-timestamp')
```

Then my template is

```
{% for comment in comment_list %}
    {{ comment }}

...
```

Is there any way to change `{% for comment in comment_list %}` to `{% for comment in new_comments_list %}` using AJAX (no page refresh)?

Or possibly changing the value of `comment_list` to equal `Comment.objects.filter().order_by('-timestamp')`?

Answer (score 2):

AJAX requests occur when the developer (you) says so. If, for example, you have set an event listener on "Clicking" a specific button to make an AJAX request then an AJAX request will be made.

Lets say you have an event listener that "listens" on a click event on a specific button with `id=my-button`.

```
{# Place this as a separate html file, say "ajax_comments.html" #}
<div id="my-placeholder">
    {% for comment in comments %}
        {{ comment }}
    {% endfor %}

    <button id="my-button">Update comments</button>
</div>
{# END OF PLACE THIS #}

{# ############################################################### #}

{# Begin of your main HTML template, say "my_template.html" #}

....

{% include 'path/to/ajax_comments.html' %}

.... 

// make an Ajax call (GET request) to the same url, using jQuery.
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#my-button').on('click', function() {
        $.ajax({
            'method': 'GET',  // defaults to GET. Set POST if you like, but be aware of the CSRF token submission too!
            'url': '.',  // submit to the same url
            'data': {},  // pass here any data to the server. You can omit it.
            success: function(dataReturned) {
                // This function will run when server returns data
                $('#my-placeholder').replaceWith(dataReturned);
            }
        });
    });
});

{# END OF "my_template.html" #}
```

Done with HTML, JS. Now to your `views.py`.

```
def my_view(request):
    if request.is_ajax():
        # If you have passed any data through the 'data' property 
        #you can get it here, according to the method used.
        my_data = request.GET.get('data-name')
        comments = Comment.objects.filter().order_by('-timestamp')
        # Note that we are passing the 'ajax_comments.html' template.
        return render(request, 'ajax_comments.html', {'comments': comments})

    comments = Comment.objects.filter().order_by('-score__upvotes')
    return render(request, 'my_template.html', {'comments': comments})
```

1. The button is pressed in your template
2. An AJAX request is made to your server
3. Inside your views, you handle this kind of request and you return an HTML portion with the **new queryset**.
4. This return is not rendered directly to the template but goes to the `$.ajax()` function which awaits for this.
5. Once received, it does what we have wrote to do (replace the `div`'s data with the new ones)

Hope this helps you!

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I've managed to change the queryset using very similar code to yours, but for some reason no javascript is working on the newly loaded child template. Do you have any idea why? I've asked a question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42126427/js-stops-working-on-child-template-when-i-perform-an-ajax-call-to-change-the-que?noredirect=1#comment71422842_42126427