# JS stops working on child template when I perform an AJAX call to change the queryset

Tags: jquery, python, ajax, django, django-templates

My `comments.html` child template looks like this:

```
<div class="commentsContainer">
    {% for comment in comment_list %} 

    ...


        {{ comment.text }} 

    ...

    {%  endfor %}

</div>
```

When I click on a button I call this AJAX function:

```
$('.comments_new').on('click', function() {
    $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: '/new_comments/',
        data: {
        },
        success: function (data) {
            $('.commentsContainer ').replaceWith(data);
        }
    })
});
```

which calls this view to change the queryset (the inital queryset is `comment_list = Comment.objects.filter().order_by('-score__upvotes')`:

```
def new_comments(request):
    if request.is_ajax():
        comment_list = Comment.objects.filter().order_by('-timestamp')
         html = {'comment_list': render_to_string('comments.html', {'comment_list': comment_list})}

         return JsonResponse(html)
```

This successfully swaps the querysets, however for some reason no javascript works on the newly loaded template/queryset. Can somebody tell me why this happens and how I can fix it?

PS: it sometimes gives this error in my terminal when the call is made: `UserWarning: A {% csrf_token %} was used in a template, but the context did not provide the value.  This is usually caused by not using RequestContext.`

Comment: Any error in the Javascript console?

Comment: No error in the JS console

Comment: I guess the `replaceWith` also wipes the event handlers. They might need to be reattached.

Comment: It depends on where your js code lives. Because it an AJAX request your first time click will work because the DOM has been parsed and listens for events. The second time, though, because the DOM has changed and no `onReady` event is fired when you click the button it will not work. In other words, your js (AJAX function) code should live inside the child template. Every time, now, the `div` is replaced, the `click` event listener will be a new one.

Comment: That makes sense. It's going to be difficult as I have many even handlers attached to the comments, so do I just copy all of them into the comments template? Or do you think it's possible to somehow link (`<script>`) the same JS file in the comments template?

Comment: What I have done in my project is this: I have defined all of my event handlers under a single object (not polluting the environment) where this obj is instatiated on document load. E.g, `var window.myObj = {'init': function(){eventHandler1(); eventHandler2();...}, 'eventHandler1': function() {...}, 'eventHandler2': ...}`, `$(document).ready(function(){myObj.init();})`. Then under my `success` function I call the event handlers that I want to (re)use, e.g `success: function(data) {... myObj.eventHandler1(); ...}`.

Comment: So I put all my event handlers togethor under 1 object? And then call a specific function from that object in my success function? I'm abit confused so is there anywhere I can read about this method further? How does every other website (like SO) do this?